# How to calculate binomial probabilities in Python?

Tags: python, math, probability

Given n number of trials, p the probability of success, what is the probability of having x successes?

```
def bin_dist(n, p, x):
```

Would using comb from scipy.special work for this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow, a website that does not do your homework for you unless you put some effort into it. Please consult this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I suggest using [math.comb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb) to calculate binomial coefficients, and what you know about binomial distributions to calculate the probability of `x` successes in `n` trials, using binomial coefficient `math.comb(n, x)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **scipy.stats** module for calculations related to statistics. For binomial distribution, **scipy.stats.binom** module can be used.
**scipy.stats.binom.stats(n, p)** can be used to calculate binomial distribution for defined value of *n and p*. It returns two values,namely **mean and variance** of the distribution
**scipy.stats.binom.pmf(r,n,p)** can be used for returning **probability mass function** for the binomial distribution at a certain value of r, n and p. A list of values from 0 to n can be passed as r to get the whole binomial distribution.